# Get site listed in Google's categorized directory at the top of some search results?

Tags: seo, google

When I googled School Information Management System
(https://www.google.com/search?q=student+information+system+software&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS746US746&oq=student+information+system+software&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61l2j69i60j0l2.6694j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

I received results like below. What makes certain results to be categorized as "Software", "Information System" ? How do I get my website to be categorized and shown in the correct category?
[image]

Comment: I haven't seen this type of result before.   I think it might be a new display treatment for their "carousel" results: https://searchengineland.com/google-adds-new-carousel-let-expand-search-results-268633

Comment: It seems like carousel is more about showing the images, not necessarily categorizing: https://www.google.com/search?q=types+of+pasta&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS746US746&oq=types+of+p&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l2j69i57j69i60j0.3055j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8